# Google Maps Android- Class ref in pre-defined class resolved to unexpected class

Tags: android, google-maps, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm making fixes to an android application already on the market. When I imported the project all the map activities gave up errors. However, the map sections are working perfectly for the app on the market. I then added maps.jar to the libs folder. All the errors in the map activities disappeared. However when I ran the application the app crashed.

The logcat in [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LGfBQN8gRobloxVzdXcVRXN0E/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the relevant part of the android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
```

Thank you for your time. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The App is crashing because you have "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in your main thread. Maybe you are missing a classpath or ClassPath attribute in your manifest. Please refer to this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html). It has explanation of this error. Hopefully, you should be able to trace the cause of this error.

Hope it helped.